# IE8 input type password browser displays the passwords instead of displaying *

Tags: internet-explorer, twitter-bootstrap

This is killing me...

this is the html code:

```
<div id="div_id_password1" class="control-group">
    <label for="id_password1" class="control-label requiredField">password<span class="asteriskField">*</span></label>
    <div class="controls">
        <input autocomplete="off" id="id_password1" type="password" class="input-xlarge textinput textInput" name="password1" /> 
    </div>
</div>
```

I'm using twitter-bootstrap.

Comment: How are you testing it? Works in IE8, even in IE7 for me.

Comment: I'm testing it with ie8 on wixp.
is there any debug tool for ie?

Comment: Oh, I was just using IE8/IE7 emulator on f12 tools on IE9.

Comment: any hint? any option to debug it?

Comment: You may want to create a JSFiddle. My guess is you have some bad markup somewhere. Does your page validate?

Comment: yes it does, this works well on FF and chrome

Comment: @DSG I wouldn't recommend using the emulator tools in IE, they do not give accurate results. It's best to use the official Microsoft virtual machines that have IE7, IE8 and IE9 pre-installed.